# How might I obfuscate a QGIS plugin written in Python

Tags: python, obfuscation, qgis

The situation is as follows: I wrote a QGIS plugin using [pluginbuilder](https://g-sherman.github.io/Qgis-Plugin-Builder/) and need to come up with a strategy to protect it. My boss would like to retain some degree of control over the use of the tool.

I initially proposed connecting to a webserver and then having the plugin remotely execute bytecode sent back from the server after authenticating. This idea was rejected due to remote code execution potential.

So far, the only thing I can think of is to try to obfuscate the code so that it is difficult to understand without effort.

I have tried several methods to no avail:

My first attempt was to try to go from .py to .c using Cython. Then I would compile the .c code to .dll using the GCC compiler.

Here is a very simple example.

```
#setup.py
import distutils.core
import Cython.Build


distutils.core.setup(
    ext_modules = Cython.Build.cythonize("example.pyx"))
```

And suppose I was attempting to convert the main interface of the plugin (example.py) to c.

```
#example.py

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
/***************************************************************************
 Example
                                 A QGIS plugin
 example
 Generated by Plugin Builder: http://g-sherman.github.io/Qgis-Plugin-Builder/
                              -------------------
        begin                : 2023-02-21
        git sha              : $Format:%H$
        copyright            : (C) 2023 by na
        email                : na
 ***************************************************************************/

/***************************************************************************
 *                                                                         *
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
 *   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
 *                                                                         *
 ***************************************************************************/
"""
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
from .resources import *
# Import the code for the dialog
from .example_dialog import ExampleDialog
import os.path


class Example:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'Example_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&example')

        # Check if plugin was started the first time in current QGIS session
        # Must be set in initGui() to survive plugin reloads
        self.first_start = None

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Example', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            # Adds plugin icon to Plugins toolbar
            self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/example/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'example'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

        # will be set False in run()
        self.first_start = True


    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&example'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)


    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
        # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = ExampleDialog()

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            pass
```

I attempted to run the following to convert the example.pyx file to c.

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

This gave me some error message related to my not having "Microsoft C++ Build Tools" on my computer. After trying to download that, I realized I needed admin privileges to install that software so I scrapped the idea not wanting to have to put in a formal request to IT for help.

After running that command, I did notice that it created something. there was an example.c file now located in my directory. Running the following command generated an `example.o` file.

```
C:\llvm-mingw-64\bin\gcc.exe -IC:\Users\username\Anaconda3\include -c -DBUILD_DLL example.c
```

I have no idea what `example.o` is. Is this some intermediary file? Here's a preview of what it contains when opened with notepad.

[example.o](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67COf.png)

Finally, when trying to build the .dll file I ran:

```
C:\llvm-mingw-64\bin\gcc.exe -IC:\Users\username\Anaconda3\include -shared -o example.dll example.o
```

I got a lot of errors:

```
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) PyModuleDef_Init
>>> referenced by example.o:(PyInit_example)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) PyObject_GetAttrString
>>> referenced by example.o:(__pyx_pymod_create)
>>> referenced by example.o:(__Pyx_copy_spec_to_module)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) PyModule_NewObject
>>> referenced by example.o:(__pyx_pymod_create)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) PyModule_GetDict
>>> referenced by example.o:(__pyx_pymod_create)
>>> referenced by example.o:(__pyx_pymod_exec_example)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) PyExc_RuntimeError
>>> referenced by example.o:(__pyx_pymod_exec_example)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) PyErr_SetString
>>> referenced by example.o:(__pyx_pymod_exec_example)
>>> referenced by example.o:(__pyx_pymod_exec_example)
>>> referenced by example.o:(__Pyx_check_single_interpreter)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) PyTuple_New
>>> referenced by example.o:(__pyx_pymod_exec_example).....
```

I then gave up on that route and decided to try `pyarmor`. (PS: I first tried nuitka, but this doesn't work with my Python version)

With pyarmor, I ran the following commands:

I wanted to generate an expired license so I ran:

```
pyarmor licenses --expired 2023-02-01 r001
```

I tried to recursively obfuscate all the plugin modules using:

```
pyarmor obfuscate --recursive --with-license licenses/r001/license.lic --output dist/example example/__init__.py
```

When I loaded the dist/example plugin into QGIS it complained about not being able to import something.

I decided to try to export each obfuscated .py file individually into dist/example and then copy that over to my QGIS plugins folder.

For example:

```
pyarmor obfuscate --with-license licenses/r001/license.lic --exact some_file.py
```

I then got the error:

```
NameError: name '__pyarmor__' is not defined
```

I tried [following this](https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/questions.html#nameerror-name-pyarmor-is-not-defined), but no luck.

**CONCLUSION**

Can anyone provide a workflow that would enable me to obfuscate, license, or protect QGIS plugin code?

I have downloaded so many installers and libraries and it seems as though everything is half-broken.

If someone has been able to successfully obfuscate plugin code and get it to work with QGIS could you share the tools you utilized and the process?

**PS** I'm also open to other suggestions - such as some kind of license mechanism.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be law.stackexchange (but it's probably a duplicate over there)

Answer (score 1):

QGis plugins are and must be licensed under the GPL version 2 or later, so there is no way to legally do what you are trying to do. You are building on the hard work of hundreds of other developers who gave time and code to the project. If you distribute your plugin then you must provide your users with access to the full source code.

If you want to hoard your code then you need to start from scratch and build your own proprietary GIS system.

Comment: Can you explain the current existence of proprietary QGIS plugins then? Comsof is one example.

Comment: To build proprietary tools off of the hard work of the open source developers who created QGIS does not discount those efforts nor does it prevent proprietary plugin developers from contributing to the development of QGIS. There is a market for plugins and an opportunity to provide companies and programmers financial incentive in that niche if the QGIS licensing terms were more compatible with the GIS industry (profit oriented). For example:  inventing a new image compression scheme and writing the code to implement it within a QGIS plugin is not a derivative work of QGIS.

Comment: QGIS plugins are just the delivery system used by end users to interact with code that implements ideas and solutions that could be considered intellectual property outside of the QGIS ecosystem.

Comment: Doesn't alter the license that applies - You include it in your question - *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
 *   (at your option) any later version.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61065/qgis-plugin-licence for further discussion

Comment: I wish I could upvote your comments. Wouldn't releasing obfuscated code and sticking a license in it still be technically compliant with GPL? User still gets the source code - it is just difficult to read.

Comment: Who cares about the spirit of the license if you can make a buck - what you are trying to do is not good.

Comment: That buck translates to employment. The spirit of the license is universal poverty. What I'm trying to do is very good.

Comment: No it doesn't - you are completely misunderstanding how it works. I and many others are employed to work on open source software.

Comment: Can you see the point that I am making? Your employer probably has proprietary software or another commodity they earn revenue from so that you are able to work on comunity projects. Or perhaps you work in academia? In the private sector, intellectual property is protected from infringement by strong legalese and other strategies like obfuscation, remote execution on servers, etc. Whatever these companies can do to avoid giving away their product for free. This is an interesting read - https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5935